# Aggregate analyzed field as plain text instead of as a term in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, aggregate

So we have an issue with our Elasticsearch cluster, by which we have some old indexes that were created with a certain field as "analyzed". Now this field can contain "-" or "_" symbols, and one of our queries aggregates by this field. 
Since this field is being analyzed, if it contains any os these characters, it aggregates by each of the words it contains. i.e:

> "analyzedField": "I-like-apples"

When we throw a query that aggregates by it like:

```
{
"query":{
  "filtered":{
     "filter":{
        [...]
     }
  }
 },
"aggs":{
 "type":{
     "terms":{
         "field":"analyzedField"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the results aggregated by each term of the field, something like:

```
{
 "took": 13,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
   "total": 10,
   "successful": 10,
   "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
   "total": 192,
   "max_score": 0,
   "hits": []
 },
 "aggregations": {
       "type": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
           {
             "key": "I",
             "doc_count": 192
           },
           {
             "key": "like",
             "doc_count": 192
           },
           {
             "key": "apples",
             "doc_count": 192
           }
```

Instead of something like:

```
{
 "took": 1,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
   "total": 10,
   "successful": 10,
   "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
   "total": 1,
   "max_score": 0,
   "hits": []
 },
 "aggregations": {
      "type": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "I-like-apples",
            "doc_count": 192
          }
```

- Unfortunately recreating these indexes with that field as "not analyzed" is not an option due to the size of them.
- So, what other options do we have? Could modify the mapping somehow so that it stops analyzing that field without having to completely re-create the index?
- How could we modify the query for it to treat that field as plain text instead of a term?

My ElasticSearch knowledge is rather basic, so excuse me if I wrote some nonsense.

Thank you
Greetings

Comment: You simply would need to re-index without analysis on that field.  If you can't do that, you are out of luck.  You have to index your data in a form that actually supports your search requirements.  Garbage in, Garbage out.

Comment: what I imagined... and how about in terms of the query? can I change so that it treats the field as not analyzed?

Comment: @femtoRgon is correct and answered the question. You cannot tweak your query and get what you want. You will need to reindex your data. You are new to ES so one thing I would recommend is reading https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale. You need to map your field as non-analyzed (use two fields and suffix the non analyzed one as -raw if you need both analyzed and non analyzed versions). Also make sure you use doc values on the non analyzed field (ES 2.0 > does this by default btw)

Comment: I see... I don't need the field to be analyzed. Yes we create the new indexes correctly (not analyzed), but there are some older ones (the biggest ones btw) that were not created correctly